# Cl-A-Cl bond angle discrepancy

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

In 2,2-dichloropropane the Cl–C–Cl angle (108.3°) is less than the C–C–C angle (113.0°).

In Me$_2$TiCl$_2$, in contrast, the Cl–Ti–Cl angle (116.7°) is larger than the C–Ti–C angle (106.2°).

How is this discrepancy explained?

Comment: This Related to the Electro negativity of atom and bond length character.